# Create object with total value from associated string array and integer array

Tags: javascript

I have a string array of product IDs, like this:
["A", "A", "B", "A"]
And another integer array of prices, like this:
[30, 50, 10, 40]

What would be the best way to produce a Javascript object with the unique item and its total cost, as the order of the integers are the prices associated with the same order of product numbers, so ideally it would return an object like this i.e.

{"A": 120, "B": 10}

Thank you!

I am relatively new to Javascript and SQL but I have tried using a foreach statement which I used successfully to produce a unique count of the item when I extract just that column into an array but not the problem as described above.

Comment: Simple reduce loop

Comment: Consider `p` as products and `c` as costs, something like this may be helpful: `console.log(p.reduce((acc, pdt, idx) => {acc[pdt] ??= 0; acc[pdt] += c[idx]; return acc; }, {} ));`. Please try and share any feedback.

Comment: Thank you, I am looking into the reduce functionality now I was not aware of it!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simple [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) loop

```js
const productIds = ["A", "A", "B", "A"];
const prices = [30, 50, 10, 40]

const totals = productIds.reduce((acc, key, index) => {
  acc[key] = (acc[key] || 0) + prices[index];
  return acc;
}, {});

console.log(totals);
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that both the arrays are of equal lengths, by using a linear search with a map to store and add the count would be the correct approach in this case:

```js
function getSummation(productIds, prices) {
  const store = {};
  for (let i=0; i < productIds.length; i++) {
    if (!store[productIds[i]])
      store[productIds[i]] = 0;
    
    store[productIds[i]] += prices[i];
  }
  return store;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Shorter version using comma operator

```js
const products = ["A", "A", "B", "A"];
const prices = [30, 50, 10, 40];
const obj = products
  .reduce((acc,cur,i) => (acc[cur] = (acc[cur] ??= 0) + prices[i], acc),{});
console.log(obj)
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const keys = ["A", "A", "B", "A"];
const values = [30, 50, 10, 40];

const result = keys.reduce((t, v, i) => ({...t, [v]: (t[v] || 0) + values[i]}), {});
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Interesting take